# Gráfico de barras com ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

Como posso fazer um gráfico com os dados abaixo comparando as duas áreas? Gostaria de deixar as barras do Cerrado do lado das barras do Bosque.
Tentei muitas vezes, mas só consegui construir o gráfico para uma das áreas. Seguem meus dados:

```
dados <- structure(list(Ordem = structure(c(7L, 5L, 2L, 8L, 10L, 6L, 9L, 
    3L, 4L, 1L, 11L), .Label = c("Blattodea", "Coleoptera", "Collembola", 
    "Dermaptera", "Diptera", "Hemiptera", "Hymenoptera", "Lepidoptera", 
    "Neuroptera", "Orthoptera", "Psocoptera", "Total"), class = "factor"), 
    Bosque = c(192L, 135L, 23L, 9L, 11L, 33L, 0L, 26L, 1L, 3L, 
    1L), Cerrado = c(128L, 130L, 13L, 9L, 1L, 35L, 3L, 23L, 0L, 
    3L, 0L)), row.names = c(NA, 11L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 2):

Primeiro tem de reformatar os dados, de formato largo para longo.

```
long <- reshape2::melt(dados, id.vars = 'Ordem')

head(long)
#        Ordem variable value
#1 Hymenoptera   Bosque   192
#2     Diptera   Bosque   135
#3  Coleoptera   Bosque    23
#4 Lepidoptera   Bosque     9
#5  Orthoptera   Bosque    11
#6   Hemiptera   Bosque    33
```

Agora é usar a coluna `value` como valor do eixo dos `y` e a coluna `variable` como variável de agrupamento/cor das barras.
A linha `theme` serve para rodar a anotação do eixo dos `x`, uma vez que há muitos grupos de barras e se ficassem na horizontal ficavam sobrepostos.

```
ggplot(long, aes(Ordem, value)) +
  geom_bar(aes(fill = variable), position = "dodge", stat="identity") +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1))
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1):

Para criar gráficos deste tipo é possível utilizar novos pacotes que podem ser interpretados como extensão, como o `ggpubr` que utiliza funções auxiliares baseadas no `ggplot2`.

```
library(tidyr)
dados <- tidyr::gather(dados, key = "Variavel", value = "valor", -Ordem)

library(ggpubr)
ggpubr::ggbarplot(dados, "Ordem", "valor",
                  fill = "Variavel", color = "Variavel",
                  label = TRUE, position = position_dodge(0.9)) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1))
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Perceba que de modo geral não há tanta diferença para o realizado por [@RuiBarradas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/389184/126988), contudo há um tom de modernismo, de avanço no código. Por exemplo, o pacote `reshape2` na teoria está [aposentado](https://github.com/hadley/reshape#status), mesmo ainda sendo muito utilizado*, contudo o indicado atualmente é o uso do `tidyr::gather`.

*eu prefiro o `reshape2::melt`ao que o `tidyr::gather`.

Comment: E agora há o `tidyr::pivot_longer`.