# Grafico em R - ggbarplot - Eixo X com Supervisor / Data

Tags: r

Não consigo fazer um gráfico pelo `ggbarplot` com o eixo X sendo supervisor e a Data.

Coloquei os meus dados para long conforme a orientação encontrada nessa outra pergunta:
[Gráfico de barras com ggplot2](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/389059/gr%c3%a1fico-de-barras-com-ggplot2)

Mas esbarro na parte que tenho que colocar no eixo X a Coluna supervisor e Data.

Segue minha estruct:

```
structure(list(SUPERVISOR = c("ALEXANDRE DE HOLANDA", "ALEXANDRE DE HOLANDA", 
"ALEXANDRE DE HOLANDA", "CARINA HELENA", "CARINA HELENA", "CARINA HELENA", 
"CÁTIA MÁXIMO", "CÁTIA MÁXIMO", "CÁTIA MÁXIMO", "KELLY CHONG", 
"KELLY CHONG", "KELLY CHONG", "LUZINETE ROSARIO", "LUZINETE ROSARIO", 
"LUZINETE ROSARIO", "MICHELLY SANTANA", "MICHELLY SANTANA", "MICHELLY SANTANA", 
"PAMELA MEDEIROS", "PAMELA MEDEIROS", "PAMELA MEDEIROS", "ALEXANDRE DE HOLANDA", 
"ALEXANDRE DE HOLANDA", "ALEXANDRE DE HOLANDA", "CARINA HELENA", 
"CARINA HELENA", "CARINA HELENA", "CÁTIA MÁXIMO", "CÁTIA MÁXIMO", 
"CÁTIA MÁXIMO", "KELLY CHONG", "KELLY CHONG", "KELLY CHONG", 
"LUZINETE ROSARIO", "LUZINETE ROSARIO", "LUZINETE ROSARIO", "MICHELLY SANTANA", 
"MICHELLY SANTANA", "MICHELLY SANTANA", "PAMELA MEDEIROS", "PAMELA MEDEIROS", 
"PAMELA MEDEIROS"), DATA = structure(c(1563148800, 1563235200, 
1563321600, 1563148800, 1563235200, 1563321600, 1563148800, 1563235200, 
1563321600, 1563148800, 1563235200, 1563321600, 1563148800, 1563235200, 
1563321600, 1563148800, 1563235200, 1563321600, 1563148800, 1563235200, 
1563321600, 1563148800, 1563235200, 1563321600, 1563148800, 1563235200, 
1563321600, 1563148800, 1563235200, 1563321600, 1563148800, 1563235200, 
1563321600, 1563148800, 1563235200, 1563321600, 1563148800, 1563235200, 
1563321600, 1563148800, 1563235200, 1563321600), class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), QUANTIDADES = c(4, 4, 4, 45, 45, 45, 
34, 34, 34, 60, 60, 60, 21, 21, 21, 1, 1, 1, 57, 57, 57, 2, 3, 
3, 38, 43, 43, 31, 31, 31, 57, 60, 60, 0, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 44, 
49, 49), TIPO = c("Total de Empresas", "Total de Empresas", "Total de Empresas", 
"Total de Empresas", "Total de Empresas", "Total de Empresas", 
"Total de Empresas", "Total de Empresas", "Total de Empresas", 
"Total de Empresas", "Total de Empresas", "Total de Empresas", 
"Total de Empresas", "Total de Empresas", "Total de Empresas", 
"Total de Empresas", "Total de Empresas", "Total de Empresas", 
"Total de Empresas", "Total de Empresas", "Total de Empresas", 
"Total de Protocolos", "Total de Protocolos", "Total de Protocolos", 
"Total de Protocolos", "Total de Protocolos", "Total de Protocolos", 
"Total de Protocolos", "Total de Protocolos", "Total de Protocolos", 
"Total de Protocolos", "Total de Protocolos", "Total de Protocolos", 
"Total de Protocolos", "Total de Protocolos", "Total de Protocolos", 
"Total de Protocolos", "Total de Protocolos", "Total de Protocolos", 
"Total de Protocolos", "Total de Protocolos", "Total de Protocolos"
)), row.names = c(NA, -42L), class = c("grouped_df", "tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), groups = structure(list(SUPERVISOR = c("ALEXANDRE DE HOLANDA", 
"CARINA HELENA", "CÁTIA MÁXIMO", "KELLY CHONG", "LUZINETE ROSARIO", 
"MICHELLY SANTANA", "PAMELA MEDEIROS"), .rows = list(c(1L, 2L, 
3L, 22L, 23L, 24L), c(4L, 5L, 6L, 25L, 26L, 27L), c(7L, 8L, 9L, 
28L, 29L, 30L), c(10L, 11L, 12L, 31L, 32L, 33L), c(13L, 14L, 
15L, 34L, 35L, 36L), c(16L, 17L, 18L, 37L, 38L, 39L), c(19L, 
20L, 21L, 40L, 41L, 42L))), row.names = c(NA, -7L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = TRUE))
```

Fiz este código para o gráfico abaixo:

```
ggpubr::ggbarplot(excel_consolidado,'SUPERVISOR', 'QUANTIDADES',
                  fill = 'TIPO',
                  label = TRUE, position = position_dodge(0.8)) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1))
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Mas gostaria que ele ficasse assim :

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Quer os valores em cima das barras, os nomes no eixo dos x em ângulo de 90 e só com o primeiro nome, e em grupos por data?

Comment: Sim, os valores devem ser demonstrados encima da barra, para acompanhamento dos valores, 
Os nomes podem aparecer de qualquer maneira, só aproveitei um print que eu tinha qui.
O ângulo não é tão importante não..

Só preciso que seja agrupado por data com os nomes, o que chegar mais simular possivel.

Comment: Feito, veja a resposta.

Comment: Perfeita a solução.
Muito Obrigado Rui.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O código que se segue faz o que a pergunta pede.
As mudanças foram:

- Com o pacote `dplyr`:

  - extrair o primeiro nome de `SUPERVISOR`.
  - Transformar a data/hora em só data.
- No gráfico:

  - `lab.size = 3` para ter anotações das barras mais pequenas.
  - `facet.by = 'DATA'` para dividir por grupos de `DATA`.
  - O eixo dos `y` foi esticado, para as anotações das barras se poderem ver.
  - Ângulo no eixo dos `x` é de 90 graus.

Quanto a ter as anotações das barras *dentro* das barras, não creio que seja útil porque algumas barras são tão pequenas que os números não cabem lá dentro. No entanto, se for necessário, basta remover o comentário da linha de código `#lab.pos = "in"`.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

excel_consolidado %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate(SUPERVISOR = str_extract(SUPERVISOR, "^[[:alpha:]]+"),
         DATA = as.Date(DATA)) %>%
  ggpubr::ggbarplot('SUPERVISOR', 'QUANTIDADES',
                  fill = 'TIPO',
                  label = TRUE, lab.size = 3,
                  #lab.pos = "in",
                  facet.by = 'DATA',
                  position = position_dodge(0.8)) +
  ylim(0, max(excel_consolidado$QUANTIDADES) + 3) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1, size = 8))
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Nossa, muito bom...
Muito Obrigado Rui.
Todas as dicas anotadas.